# how can I parse parameter to XZ compressor in dar?

Tags: archive

in tar I can use `XZ_OPT='-9e --thread=10'`, how can I do this in dar. At least I want to be able to use multithread xz compressor. Any idea how to achieve this?

The same env does not work for dar, it is always single threaded.